# Role of physics in the zeta function $\zeta$ and the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

[Hilbert and Polya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_conjecture) suggested a physical way to verify the Riemann hypotesis about $\zeta(x)$. If the Riemann hypotesis is true, we can state all eigenvalues of physical problems are real. What is the connection between the eigenvalues and the $\zeta$ function?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26856/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

In http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03679 , the authors consider a Hamiltonian

$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{I-\exp(-i\hat{p})}(\hat{x}\hat{p}+\hat{p}\hat{x})(I-\exp(-i\hat{p}))$,

where $I$ is the identity matrix (I suppose - I cannot type the symbol they use), and claim that "a formal calculation of the eigenstates $\{\psi_n\}$ and
eigenvalues $\{E_n\}$ of $\hat{H}$ shows that with the boundary condition $\psi_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ the eigenvalues satisfy the property that $\{\frac{1}{2}(1-iE_n)\}$ are the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function. This non-Hermitian form of the Hilbert-Polya conjecture thus confirms the Berry-
Keating conjecture."