# Algebraic number theory and physics

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, mathematics

I would like to ask if there are any aspects of algebraic number theory related to physics (for example in string theory or Moonshine etc).

I am thinking of attending a course on algebraic number theory but in order to decide I would like to know how useful it might end up being for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number theory in Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414/)

Comment: Number theory is well known to be related to physics via moonshine. I want to know about aspects of algebraic number theory though.